# php Mongo how to pass a variable to a cursor

Tags: php, mongodb

I am unfamiliar with the syntax to pass a variable to a mongo cursor.
Currently I have the 'name' hardcoded as 'ABC'.
But I want to be able to pass a variable instead of hardcoding 'ABC'.

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost");
$dbs = $client ->database_name->table_name; // $client -> DBNAME -> COLLECTION_NAME
$result = $dbs -> find(array('name' => 'ABC'));
```

I tried this, but it is not working.

```
$name = 'ABC';
$result = $dbs -> find(array('name' => $name));
```

Can someone please provide me with the correct syntax?
Thanks

Comment: There is no functional difference between your first and second example. Can you define, "not working"?